# matplotlib is no running in VS

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am practicing matplotlib. I am using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    y = [1,2,3,4,5]
    x = [10,12,5,8,3]

    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.title('Line Chart')
    plt.xlabel('x-axis')
    plt.ylabel('y-axis')
    plt.show
```

There is not issue with it, but the graph is not shown.

I installed matplotlib already. I can't find the library as extension in
VS

This is what I got in the console (including the space in-between):

"PS C:\Users\HP>

> & C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe "c:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Python Training/Matplotlib Training 1.py"
> PS C:\Users\HP> "

Thank.

#I am expecting to visualize the data.

Comment: `plt.show` should be `plt.show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `plt.show` to `plt.show()`  to execute the show method.